# How to change the display position of recipients in Outlook 2013?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

By default, Outlook 2013 displays the recipients of an email
at the top of the window, above the subject line:

[image: attachment1]

I want to change the position of the recipient list to be under the subject:

[image: attachment2]

but failed to find a configurable setting for it.

How can I make this change?

Comment: Change the position in what way? What's you're desired end state?

Comment: I've uploaded another end state pic, I want to change the position from pic1 to pic2, you see the difference?

Comment: That's better. You should pluralize "recipients" since you want to move all of them, not just one.

Comment: I don't think it's possible.

Comment: If that's possible, why there has 2 different positions appear in the pic above?